# Show $\exists X,Y,Z \subset S$ disjoint and $|X|=|Y|=|Z|=c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given $|S| = c$ and $c$ here represents the continuum.

Given $x,y,z \in S$ distinct. Want to show $\exists X,Y,Z \subset S$ such that $|X|=|Y|=|Z|=c$ and $x \in X, y \in Y, z \in Z$.

I tried defining $f: S \to [0,1]$ and given $x,y,z\in S$ $f(x),f(y),f(z)\in[0,1].$

I can always find a subinterval of $[0,1]$ such that they are disjoint and $x,y,z$ is in each subinterval.

Would this be a correct proof idea? Or am I approaching this wrong... Thanks.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you would be able to *define* a function $f$. I would find it more credible if you somehow were able to guarantee the existence of such an $f$, and presumably imbue $f$ with some specific properties (one-to-one? onto? both? neither?) from which you could deduce the existence of the desired $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Also, $x$,$y$, and $z$ do not “live” in $[0,1]$, so you can’t find subintervals with them...

Comment: Okay I know there exists a bijection, sorry for the poor wording by saying define. What do I do next?

Comment: Your idea is fine, but you need to flesh it out and complete it. And be careful; again, you claim something about $x$, $y$, and $z$ as if they were elements of $[0,1]$. They aren’t.

Comment: I meant $f(x), f(y), f(z) \in [0,1]$ I can find disjoint subsets of $[0,1]$ for each $f(x),f(y),f(z)$ but how do I make it for $S$? Maybe because $f$ is bijective so I can do something but not sure what.

Comment: It’s not enought that they be subsets; you need them to have a certain cardinality. As to “not sure what”... what is *the* defining characteristic of a bijecive function? It has an inverse.

Comment: Yes, it has an inverse. But $f^{-1}: [0,1] \to S$ and if I apply the inverse function onto $f(x),f(y),f(z)$ it just becomes $x,y,z \in S$. I don't think that helps me. What would the inverse help me with?

Comment: You can also apply it to *subsets* of $[0,1]$....

Comment: So I first find the subintervals in $[0,1]$ then apply the inverse function on the disjoint subintervals I found? Also, how should I pick be picking the subintervals of $[0,1]$? I was thinking letting $f(x) \in [0, 0.33]$ and $f(y) \in [0.34, 0.6]$ and $f(z) \in [0.61, 0.99]$ clearly all disjoint sets. Or do I have change those subintervals for arbitrary values in $[0,1]$?

Comment: You don’t know where $f(x)$, $f(y)$, and $f(z)$ are. You only know they are in $[0,1]$ and are distinct. You can’t “let” $f(x)$ be in $[0,0.33]$, becuause you don’t define $f$.  So you’ll need to **prove** that you can find three disjoint intervals, each one containing exactly one of $f(x)$, $f(y)$, and $f(z)$, **no matter** what the latter are. That is: that given any three elements of $[0,1]$. you can break up $[0,1]$ into three disjoint sets, each one containing exactly one of the given elements. That is, if you want to push this particular line towards a proof.

Comment: Okay so, I know $f(x) \in [0,1]$ denote $f(x)=r$. Since I have 3 elements to work with to create 3 disjoint sets I am really tempted to take the length of the interval and divide by 3. Should I choose interval $[a,b]$? Or can I still work with $[0,1]$ to make three disjoints sets with the conditions that is needed>

Comment: This has gone beyond what comments are for. No, you cannot divide the interval in three equal parts, **because you don't know ahead of time where exactly $f(x)$, $f(y)$, and $f(z)$ will be**. What you need to prove to make this work is something like "Given **any** three numbers $r,t,u$ in $[0,1]$, different from each other, there are uncountable subsets $R$, $T$, and $U$ of $[0,1]$, pairwise disjoint, with $r\in R$, $t\in T$, and $u\in U$."

Comment: Okay, thanks. I know there are infinitely many subintervals in $[0,1]$. And that is why you are allowed to say "there are uncountable subsets $R,T,U$ pairwise disjoint, etc." Is this a statement that comes logically or from conclusions of some theorems/definitions? After all this I would take the inverse functions of the sets $R,T,U$ because it would correspond to some set in $S$ because the inverse function is bijective, correct?

Comment: No; the fact that there are infinitely many subintervals has nothing to do with this. The "uncountable" refers to the size each of $R$, $T$, and $U$, not to how many such intervals there are. I don't think we are communicating, so I don't think I can be of any help here. The statement in question is something you would need to *prove* to push through your idea. Alternatively, you can abandon this approach and seek a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely there exists a bijection $f:S\to \Bbb R $ and $r=  \frac {1}{2}\min \{|f(x)-f(y)|, |f(y)-f(z)|,|f(z)-f(x)|\} \in \Bbb R^+.$

So let $X=f^{-1}(-r+f(x),r+f(x))$ and $Y=f^{-1}(-r+f(y),r+f(y))$ and $Z=f^{-1}(-r+f(z),r+f(z)).$